# Required variable found value java?

Tags: java

I have been working on a program for class that compares values of two temps. I've got everything working but on my very last method I am getting an error, even though it is built the exact same. The is not equal to function is saying required variable found value and wont run, even though the rest that are built the same way do run?

```
 public boolean isLessThan(Temperature t){

 return t.get()>this.get();
 }
 public boolean isGreaterThan(Temperature t){
    return t.get()>this.get();
 }
 public boolean isEqual(Temperature t){
    return (Math.abs(this.get()-t.get()))<=10E-12;

 }

 public boolean isGreaterThanOrEqual(Temperature t){
     return t.get()>=this.get();

 }
 public boolean isLessThanorEqual(Temperature t){
     return (t.get()<=this.get());}

 public boolean isNotEqualTo(Temperature t){
    return Math.abs(this.get()-t.get())=>10E-12;
 }



}
```

Answer (score 3):

Well... the operator is wrong.

```
<= // less or equal
>= // bigger or equal
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax here

```
return Math.abs(this.get()-t.get())=>10E-12;
```

(assuming you want greater then or equal to) needs to be

```
return Math.abs(this.get()-t.get()) >= 10E-12;
```

Also, this

```
public boolean isLessThan(Temperature t){
  return t.get()>this.get();
}
```

should be

```
public boolean isLessThan(Temperature t){
  return t.get() < this.get();
}
```

Comment: So my prof has a tester program and it goes through all my methods and tells me which are wrong, and it compares two values that are the same, and in each of them one of mine is true and the other is false, where they should both be true or both false. Any ideas on what would cause this?

Comment: I notice isnotequalto has an equals sign in the test.